# DrawerLayout End gravity. Drawer not opening with edge swipe when as child

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout, viewgroup

I was working on the landscape layout for my activity. In landscape activity I happen to have the layout with xml code below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Problem arising here is that the drawer is not opening by edge swipe. BTW using LTR layout so end is right. By java invocation for opening drawer, the Drawer opens and touch events are also handled. Also all drawers are Unlocked as well. But still Drawer doesn't opens by swipe from right edge when Drawer layout is child of linear layout with horizontal orientation. if the first Frame:ayout in the linearLayout is of zero width then the drawer works.

Whats wrong with the Drawer Layout? How Can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From the Android reference:

> DrawerLayout acts as a top-level container for window content

The `DrawerLayout` needs to be the root element of the view. It can't be nested in the `LinearLayout`